# Rstudio IF statement

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question regarding to Rstudio if statement. I want to create an if statement such that if a matrix I generated contains all 0 values, then a matrix called "Para" would give also give three 0 values, else it the data would be used to estimate parameters for Pearson Type 3 distribution.
Here is the code I wrote and the error message I got.

```r
timeScale<-3
SNOmm_1_3mon <- read.delim('SNOmm_1.txt')
X<-as.numeric(as.character(unlist(SNOmm_1_3mon[,1])))
nVal <- length(X)
nYear <- nVal/12
Q <- matrix(0,12,1)
para<- matrix(0,12,3)
totWindows <- nVal - timeScale +1
SWEI <- matrix(0,totWindows,1)
nWindow <-0

for(k in 1:12){
  endMonth <- timeScale+k-1
  if (endMonth>12){
    nYear2 <- nYear-1
  } else {
    nYear2 <- nYear
  }
  precipCum <- matrix(0,nYear,1)
  for(i in 1:nYear2){
    nWindow<-nWindow+1
    sumVal<-0
    for(j in 1:timeScale){
      sumVal <- sumVal+X[(i-1)*12+endMonth-j+1]
    }
    precipCum[i,1] <- sumVal
    
  }
  **if(precipCum <- matrix(0,nYear2,1)){
    para[k,] <- matrix(0,3,1)
  } else {
    Lmoment<-samlmu(precipCum)
    parameter<-pelpe3(Lmoment)
    para[k,]<-parameter
  }**

  
}
```

Error message:

```r
Error in pelxxx("pe3", lmom) : pelpe3: missing values in L-moment vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (precipCum <- matrix(0, nYear2, 1)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In samlmu(precipCum) : all data values equal
```

How does if statement work in Rstudio?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if there are other problems without seeing the data, but at the very least this `if(precipCum <- matrix(0,nYear2,1))` should be changed to `if(precipCum == matrix(0,nYear2,1))`

Comment: Your code-formatted code includes `**if`, which seems unlikely. I realize you are trying to highlight it, unfortunately SO markdown formatting does not work in that fashion. While in this case it seems trivial for us to detect and fix those before possibly attempting your code, it is generally *much* better/safer if you provide real code that we can copy and paste into our R console without intervention like that.